# Can I use a 2016 MacBook pro charger on a 2019 MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro

I’m borrowing a 16 inch 2019 MacBook Pro while my 2016 is in the shop, I figured I could use the same charger being USB-C and it would just charge slow but it doesn’t seem to be charging at all... is it just slow or do I need the other charger?

Comment: It should charge. I can charge my 2017" MacBook with a USB plug (5V) and also with a Powerbank that supports USB-C (at 9V I think)... Can you try a different charger and cable?

Comment: I was also able to power a 2017 MBP with a 9V @ 3A, 27 watt, charger while not losing charge.  A MBP should not consume more than the power a 61 or 87 watt charger can supply unless under very heavy load.  There are plenty of possible causes for this behavior, a damaged charger or cable, or a loose connection somewhere, are among those possibilities.  Check the CPU load to rule that out as some process may be taking a lot of power without your knowing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wattage requirement of the 2019 MacBook Pro (96W) is greater than the capability of the 2016 charger (87W), so it will either charge slowly, hold its charge level, or continue to lose charge slowly, depending on usage.

Analogy time: imagine a bath half full of water (the battery). The plug is removed, and water leaves the bath (energy used by the laptop). You add water by turning on the tap (Recharging).

If the tap can't supply water fast enough to match the water going out, then the bath level (battery) will continue to fall, but at a slower rate than no water going in at all.

If the tap can supply only a little bit more than the water going out, then the level will rise, but slowly.

With the laptop shut, it should still gain charge, but a bit slower than usual.

Comment: The probability of such a small difference in power output between the two chargers causing a MBP to lose charge while in use is quite low.  A 9 watt difference is less than 10%, and just because a laptop came with a 96 watt charger does not mean it will consume all 96 watts under load.  There have been complaints of some Apple laptops requiring more power than the included power supply could provide, but such people were running overnight video renders and had put extra cooling to allow higher power consumption.  I was able to run a 2017 MBP on a 27 watt charger for hours while web surfing.

Answer (score 0):

The 2019 MacBook Pro charger works just fine with the 2016 MacBook Pro - and vice versa. The charging speed should be exactly the same in the former case, and almost the same in the latter case.

The two chargers are both USB-C, while the 2016 MacBook Pro charger tops out at 87W - the 2019 charger tops out at 96W. The computer and charger will automatically make sure that the correct charge is applied.

Comment: I think it's the other way round: the 2016 charger is supposed to charge the 2019 MacBook, but still, the answer is it **should** work

Comment: Ah, but yes doesn’t matter - it works either way. The wattage is plenty to charge a 2019 MacBook Pro, as long as you’re not compiling or 3D gaming 24/7.